# NU1002 The dependency BlockchainAPI 3.1.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Tags: api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new application using the framework NET Core 1.0 , and  installed the package of BlockchainAPI 3.1.0 in that , now i am getting this error :

> NU1002 The dependency BlockchainAPI 3.1.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp , Version=v1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 "buildOptions": {
     "debugType": "portable",
     "emitEntryPoint": true
 }
```